# Owin Startup.cs in ASP.NET IIS Hosted Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, katana

I am wondering how OWIN is working on asp.net projects hosted on iis.
Specifically i am talking about the startup.cs
When i reference Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb and add a Startup.cs class it gets fired. I think it adds a httpmodule to the iis pipeline, and this class calls the startup class if not already done? But why is no entry in the web.config to register this module?
I could not find a good article explaining a bit more in deep how this is working. Could someone explain me this? :)

thank you in advance

best

Laurin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the OWIN/Katana startup.cs in ASP.NET projects on IIS is usually called in the Global.asax.cs

This changed a little bit in ASP.NET 5  since there's no Global.asax anymore and it should be automatically done in Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS (BTW: The Katana project is dead and completely integrated in ASP.NET 5)

Cheers
Juergen